# Error with datetime column while serialising a DataFrame into an HDF5 store

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, pandas, hdf5

I'm trying to save a DataFrame into an HDF5 store using pandas builtin function to_hdf
but this raises the following exception:

> File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pytables.py", line 3433, in > >create_axes
>      raise e
>   TypeError: Cannot serialize the column [date] because
>   its data contents are [datetime] object dtype

the dataframe is built from a numpy array with correct types for each column

I tried to convert_object() as I read in other frames but it still fails

here is my test code, I am obviously missing something with the data conversion but cant figure out what

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

columns = ['date', 'c1', 'c2']

# building a sample test numpy array with datetime, float and integer
dtype = np.dtype("datetime64, f8, i2")
np_data = np.empty((0, len(columns)), dtype=dtype)
for i in range(1, 3):
    line = [datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, i), i/2, i*1000]
    np_data = np.append(np_data, np.array([line]), axis=0)
print('##### the numpy array')
print(np_data)

# creating DataFrame from numpy array
df = pd.DataFrame(np_data, columns=columns)
# trying to force object conversion
df.convert_objects()
print('##### the DataFrame array')
print(df)

# the following fails!
try:
    df.to_hdf('store.h5', 'data', append=True)
    print('worked')
except Exception, e:
    print('##### the error')
    print(e)
```

The code above produces the following output

```
##### the numpy array
[[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 1) 0 1000]
 [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12, 2) 1 2000]]
##### the DataFrame array
                  date c1    c2
0  2015-01-01 12:01:00  0  1000
1  2015-01-01 12:02:00  1  2000
##### the error
Cannot serialize the column [date] because
its data contents are [datetime] object dtype
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all pandas operations return *new* objects. Your `.convert_objects()` operation discarded the output.

```
In [20]: df2 = df.convert_objects()

In [21]: df.dtypes
Out[21]: 
date    object
c1      object
c2      object
dtype: object

In [22]: df2.dtypes
Out[22]: 
date    datetime64[ns]
c1               int64
c2               int64
dtype: object
```

Save/restore

```
In [23]: df2.to_hdf('store.h5', 'data', append=True)

In [25]: pd.read_hdf('store.h5','data')
Out[25]: 
                 date  c1    c2
0 2015-01-01 12:01:00   0  1000
1 2015-01-01 12:02:00   1  2000

In [26]: pd.read_hdf('store.h5','data').dtypes
Out[26]: 
date    datetime64[ns]
c1               int64
c2               int64
dtype: object
```

Finally, it is more idiomatic, to directly construct the dataframe. Types are inferred on construction.

```
In [32]: DataFrame({'data' : pd.date_range('20150101',periods=2,freq='s'),'c1' : [0,1], 'c2' : [1000,2000]},columns=['data','c1','c2']).dtypes
Out[32]: 
data    datetime64[ns]
c1               int64
c2               int64
dtype: object
```